# Adding an element to list in specified dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'array': [[], [], []]})

# need to add an element in index 0
df[df.index==0].array[0].append(1) # works! add 1 to first row

df[df.index==1].array[0].append(2) # doesnt work!
df[df.index==1].array[1].append(2) # works! add 2 to second row
df.array[3].append(10) # works! add 10 to 3rd row
```

my question is why? I dont get it. What if I want to add multiple of similar element to multiple list?

```
df[df.index>0].array.append(2) # obviously does not work
```

**[Explanation]**

A bit of explanation. I think part of the issue arises in how I create my original dataframe

```
# This was how I created it
df = pd.DataFrame({'array': 3 * [[]]})

# It gives different result than this method:
df = pd.DataFrame({'array': [[] for i in range(3)]

# Or this method:
df = pd.DataFrame({'array': [[], [], []] })
```

Aside from that, I realized it is pretty similar. The answers here gives more explanation than on the linked thread though. So hopefully this question can stay. DO let me know if I need to delete this thread as I want to save all the answers and suggestions from people here.

Comment: When you use `.array[i]` `i` referes to the index. In the second case, you slice by `index == 1`, but then try to access the element with index = 0, which clearly doesn't exist in that subset

Comment: `df.array[3].append(10)` shouldn't work either...

Comment: This is part of the reason that `.loc` and `.iloc` indexers exist, to avoid this kind of ambiguity, as well as `df['array']` column access, rather than accessing columns via `df.array` as you would an attribute. It makes for better self-documenting code.

Comment: lol you are right , it's supposed to be df.array[2].append(10).

Comment: @ALollz How do I mass update (based on certain condition) then?

Comment: @G.Anderson this works for me `df.loc[df.index>0, ['array']]['array'].apply(lambda x: x.append(1)`. But I still dont fully grasp the idea with all these ambiguity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas add item to a series of list data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124744/pandas-add-item-to-a-series-of-list-data-type)

Comment: @aghast I made that thread and I am aware of it before I made this one. It's different question. I am trying to append to specific rows only in the same dataframe this time.

Comment: @aghast I have updated the post with explanation

Answer (score 2):

When you call `df[df.index==1]` you're getting the follwing:

```
1    []
Name: array, dtype: object
```

**Note the number 1** -- you are slicing the index so it makes sense that when you try to access it:

```
df[df.index==1].array[0]
```

It's trying to get a **zeroth** element that isn't there. For this and other reasons, `pandas` provides `iloc` and `loc`. The following executes and results as expected:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'array': [[], [], []]})
df.iloc[0].array.append(0)
df.iloc[1].array.append(2)
df.iloc[0].array.append(0)
df.iloc[1].array.append(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in df[df.index>0].array:
    x.append(2)
```

`df[df.index>0].array.append(2)` does not work because `df[df.index>0].array` returns a series of lists, so we have to enumerate this series and insert into the each list.

Comment: this works but I was quite sure It didnt work for me previously. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to append items to lists in your cells, using a logical expression to select which items, you'll need a different approach.

Pandas uses the "normal" method-names for operating on sequences to refer to the *actual Pandas dataframe*. So you can't just do `a[i].append` in the same way you would do `a[i] *= 2`. :-(

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54124744/4029014) has a bunch of useful answers. I think the one you want probably looks like this:

```
h[1] >>> print(f)
  array
0    []
1    []
2    []
h[1] >>> f[f.index>0].array.apply([2].__add__)
1    [2]
2    [2]
Name: array, dtype: object
```

Comment: I just realized it has some similarity. This thread has more varied answers though especially for appending to a single row of list datatype. Thanks for highlighting @aghast

Answer (score 1):

Can still use `.loc`

```
df.loc[df.index < 2, 'array'] = df.loc[df.index < 2, 'array'] + [4]

#  array
#0   [4]
#1   [4]
#2    []
```

Though it's not any faster than the slow apply. This is typically why you don't store `list` objects in a `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the issue is that it appears you are attempting to access indexes that don't actually exist, so you'll want to be sure they do. In order to append your array you could use either [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas.DataFrame.iloc) or [`iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html#pandas.DataFrame.iat), the latter is generally what is recommended for accessing indexes by integer:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'array': [[], [], []]})

# need to add an element in index 0
df.iat[0,0].append(1)  # works! add 1 to first row
df.iat[1,0].append(2)  # works! add 2 to second row
df.iat[1,0].append(2)  # works! add another 2 to second row
df.iat[2,0].append(10) # works! add 10 to 3rd row
```

Result:

```
    array
0     [1]
1  [2, 2]
2    [10]
```

> **iat** 
>  
>   <sub>Access a single value for a row/column pair by integer position. Similar to [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas.DataFrame.iloc), in that both provide integer-based lookups. 
>   **Use [iat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html#pandas.DataFrame.iat) if you only need to get or set a single value in a DataFrame or Series.**</sub>

↳ [pandas.DataFrame.iat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html#pandas-dataframe-iat)